# How to make a swiper with visibility of objects on the sides

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I'm learning web development. Now I'm programming my site. To implement the slider on it, I use Swiper. I learned how to make slider with one object displayed in a block (the first picture: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rIpY.png)). I need to make a slider so that in the block some of the other objects are visible (second picture:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz5kp.png)).

I tried increasing the width of the slider block but this resulted in incorrect display of objects (third picture:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oncaS.png). The "slidesPerView" parameter also causes objects to be displayed incorrectly (fourth picture:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Vzc.png)). I would be grateful if you could explain or give a tip on how to do this. Thank you for your attention.